# Notify by email, when a value from a specific column to changed, using Script Editor

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-sheets

I need to notify by email when any cells in the AQ column of my spreadsheet are changed.

I wrote a formula that is not working.

An image of the spreadsheet and the formula are below.

[image]

```
    function onEdit( e ){
  //To get email notification if any changes to the perticular cells
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Notificações");
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "fabiano.ars95@outlook.com";
  var message = ''; 
  if(cell.indexOf('AQ')!=-1) { // means that if you edit column AQ
    message = sheet.getRange('AQ'+
      sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
}
var subject ='Notificação de Alta Prioridade '
var body =' Você acaba de receber uma notificação de alta prioridade. Acesse sua planilha de notificações para que possa elaborar uma tratativa' 
Logger.log(body); 
//MailApp.sendEmail("fabiano.ars95@outlook.com","Notificação de alta prioridade","Você acaba de receber uma notificação de alto risco, acesse sua planilha de notificações para que possa elaborar uma tratativa;
```

Comment: Please convert the code to text and place it in your question.  Images are frowned upon.

Comment: Also some googling yielded this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/send-emails-excel-vba/

Answer (score 0):

your braces are in the wrong spots, here is the correct code:

```
  function onEdit(){
  //To get email notification if any changes to the perticular cells
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Notificações");
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "fabiano.ars95@outlook.com";
  var message = ''; 
  if(cell.indexOf('AQ')!=-1) {// means that if you edit column AQ
    message = sheet.getRange('AQ'+   sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
    var subject ='Notificação de Alta Prioridade '
    var body =' Você acaba de receber uma notificação de alta prioridade. Acesse sua planilha de notificações para que possa elaborar uma tratativa' 
    Logger.log(body); 
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,subject,body);
  }
}
```

Comment: I really apreciate your help, but this appear when i had try run : TypeError: The "getActiveRange" method of null can not be called. (Line 6, file "Code") Ignore. I'm realy begginer on java script, if you can help me again...

qualidade.caxiasdor@gmail.com
Sair
Notificação
ArquivoEditarVisualizarExecutarPublicarRecursosAjuda
             onEdit

Comment: you need to make sure you have a sheet called "Notificações".

Comment: Hey, in the first time the code Worked fine, but now it's popping up Select an active page first. (Line 5, file "Code")

Comment: Can you share the sheet so I can look at it?